# Want to assign opportunity owner user as account owner?

Tags: apex, trigger, configuration

Can anyone help me with the code or declarative way

I have a scenario where i need to assign opportunity owner to account owner based on the below conditions

1. whenever opportunity being changed to closed Lost, that opportunity user name should be assigned as Account owner
2. Stage name should be closed lost

Comment: Can you at least tell us what you tried so far?

Comment: You should really read this [tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/business_process_automation/units/process_builder) about the Salesforce process builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Setup ->Process Builder
2. Click on New Button -> Enter the Process Name -> The process starts when->  A Record Changes-> Save
3. Select the Object -> Opportunity -> Start the process-> when a record is created or edited -> Save
4. Enter Criteria Name -> Choose Criteria for Executing Actions -> Set Conditions ->Opportunity.StageName  Equals PickList 'Closed Lost' -> Choose All of the conditions are met (AND) ->Save

   [image: Set Conditions]
5. Add Immediate Actions -> Select Action Type -> Update Records ->Enter Action Name -> Select a Record to Update ->Select a record related to the Opportunity
   -> Select AccountID -> Set new field values for the records you update -> Field ->OwnerId -> Type -> Reference ->Opportunity.OwnerId -> Save
6. Finally Activate Process Builder.

   [image: Set new field values for the records you update]